# How to connect JDBC remotely

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle, macos, jdbc

I'm a mac user, I have the oracle database in a virtual machine, and I've been working on it pretty well, I've been installed also Eclipse on my Mac machine, my problem begins now that I need to connect them.

Is there any way I can connect to my oracle database remotely with the IP address on the virtual machine?

In other words connect my Eclipse installed on mac to my oracle database installed on my windows virtual machine.

Comment: Assuming you've set it up so that your Mac can talk to services inside the Windows VM, why not? Are you stuck on something?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done and is a common scenario for development. Depending on the flavour of virtual machine you are using (VMWare, virtualbox, etc) the details will differ, but  you will either need to set up port forwarding of the relevant oracle ports onto your host machine (the Mac), or configure bridged networking so the virtual machine with oracle has it's own IP address on the network.

I tend to just port forward and use NAT, which means I can connect to the database using the normal jdbc connection string, with the hostname section set to localhost.  The schematic diagram below should give you a rough idea of what's going on.

```
              +--------------------------------------+
              |                                      |
              |                                      |
              |                                      v
              |                              +-------+-----------+
              |                              |                   |
              |                              |   1512            |
+--------------------------------------------+------+-----+------++
|             |            Host Machine (Mac)       | NAT + PortForwarding
|             |                                     |             |
|             |                                     |             |
|             |                                     |             |
|             |                                     |             |
|             |                                     v             |
|             |                              +------+-----------+ |
|             |                              |     1512         | |
|             |                +-------------+------------------+ |
|             |                |                                | |
|   +---------+-------------+  |                                | |
|   |   java application    |  |                                | |
|   |                       |  |                                | |
|   |                       |  |                                | |
|   |db-url=localhost:1512/ |  |            ORACLE VM           | |
|   |                       |  |                                | |
|   |                       |  |                                | |
|   |                       |  |                                | |
|   |                       |  |                                | |
|   +-----------------------+  |                                | |
|                              +--------------------------------+ |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

For details on how to set up NAT/portforwding on virtualbox, see this relevant section in this link: https://www.howtogeek.com/122641/how-to-forward-ports-to-a-virtual-machine-and-use-it-as-a-server/